# Why do some of my Google Sheets fields not populate?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to this, so I appreciate your help. I'm trying to get values from OpenWeatherMaps on my associated Google Sheet when making an API call.

But I'm missing something basic that I can't figure out: some fields (Current Temperature/Today's High/Tonight's Low/Feels Like/Humidity) populate in the Sheet while others (ID/Main/Description/Icon) do not. How have I failed? (I have removed my API key from the code.)

```
function getCurrentData() {
  // API key
  const key = "{insert API here}"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const wsLocation = ss.getSheetByName("Location")
  const wsLiveData = ss.getSheetByName("Live Data")
  const location = wsLocation.getRange("A2").getValue()
  const tempCell = wsLiveData.getRange("A4")
  const highCell = wsLiveData.getRange("B4")
  const lowCell = wsLiveData.getRange("C4")
  const feelslikeCell = wsLiveData.getRange("D4")
  const idCell = wsLiveData.getRange("E4")
  const mainCell = wsLiveData.getRange("F4")
  const descriptionCell = wsLiveData.getRange("G4")
  const iconCell = wsLiveData.getRange("H4")
  const humidityCell = wsLiveData.getRange("I4")

  let apiURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=39.952583&lon=-75.165222&units=imperial&description=&icon=&appid={insert API here}"

  const resText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL).getContentText()
  const resJSON = JSON.parse(resText)
  const temp = (resJSON["main"]["temp"])
  const tempMin = (resJSON["main"]["temp_min"])
  const tempMax = (resJSON["main"]["temp_max"])
  const feelslike = (resJSON["main"]["feels_like"])
  const id = (resJSON["weather"]["id"])
  const main = (resJSON["weather"]["main"])
  const description = (resJSON["weather"]["description"])
  const icon = (resJSON["weather"]["icon"])
  const humidity = (resJSON["main"]["humidity"])
  tempCell.setValue(temp)
  lowCell.setValue(tempMin)
  highCell.setValue(tempMax)
  feelslikeCell.setValue(feelslike)
  idCell.setValue(id)
  mainCell.setValue(main)
  descriptionCell.setValue(description)
  iconCell.setValue(icon)
  humidityCell.setValue(humidity)
}
```

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: {"coord":{"lon":-75.1652,"lat":39.9526},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":59.09,"feels_like":58.03,"temp_min":55.51,"temp_max":61.99,"pressure":1018,"humidity":71},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":6.91,"deg":70},"clouds":{"all":100},"dt":1698587046,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2037403,"country":"US","sunrise":1698578751,"sunset":1698616964},"timezone":-14400,"id":4560349,"name":"Philadelphia","cod":200}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is much better to add requested details to your original question than putting them in a comment. Please [edit] your question adding those details; you can delete your command afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem:

```
function testie() {
  const data = JSON.parse('{"coord":{"lon":-75.1652,"lat":39.9526},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":59.09,"feels_like":58.03,"temp_min":55.51,"temp_max":61.99,"pressure":1018,"humidity":71},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":6.91,"deg":70},"clouds":{"all":100},"dt":1698587046,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2037403,"country":"US","sunrise":1698578751,"sunset":1698616964},"timezone":-14400,"id":4560349,"name":"Philadelphia","cod":200}'); 
  Logger.log('temp: %s feels: %s windspeed: %s',data.main.temp,data.main.feels_like,data.wind.speed);
  Logger.log('temp: %s feels: %s windspeed: %s',data["main"]["temp"],data["main"]["feels_like"],data["wind"]["speed"]);
  
}

Execution log
11:06:42 AM Notice  Execution started
11:06:43 AM Info    temp: 59.09 feels: 58.03 windspeed: 6.91
11:06:43 AM Info    temp: 59.09 feels: 58.03 windspeed: 6.91
11:06:43 AM Notice  Execution completed
```